# Flex: Complex Drag and Drop

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flex4

I have a project with a GUI that has collapsible panels, then within those panels are items you can drag and drop to a "stage" area and it adds the media element to the stage. I'm using this collapsible panel code: http://www.iwobanas.com/2009/09/creating-collapsible-panel-in-flex-4/

However, I also need this GUI to be changeable, so that the user can move the panels wherever they want.

I tried doing a simple drag/drop system on the panels, but there were two main issues

1. Adding the drag event removed the ability to collapse the panel (as both were mouse events)
2. Dragging the panel onto the "stage" treated it the same as a media element, and would throw a null object reference because it obviously isn't a media element.

So I figured I'd add an if statement to ignore anything that wasn't a media element. This didn't work either, I traced out the information,

```
var itemTL:TileList = event.dragInitiator as TileList;
trace("This is the Dragged init " + itemTL.selectedItem.appListElement);
```

However both a media element and the panel itself trace out similar information, without really much I can pull out to build an if statement from.

So I'm kind of stuck wondering how to make a collapsible panel that can be moved around a stage, but not actually added to the stage like the information in the panel itself.

Comment: This seems to be heavily dependent on your class structure. If you can contain all your classes properly so that all your sub classes extend `Panel` and wrap that in a Sprite or MC then you should be able to make `Panel` a moveable object leaving all operations inside, independent. Can you maybe post some pseudo of your class structure or maybe more code in general?

Comment: I inherited this project with no documentation at all, so I'm not 100% confident on the structure.

Structurally there's one main class, the canvas itself. This has the master drag/drop because it was built without the ability to drag/drop the GUI around, so it's been told to accept anything from the menus dropped onto it, including the menu itself. The panel has its own class, as does every media element within that panel.

If I were to redo it myself, now, I'd do what you're suggesting, but the project is now almost 60 classes big, so redoing huge portions is just not financially feasible.

Comment: understood...it seems some of the elements are likely dependent on their origin, which would muck everything up once you get deep into the classes. its ugly but what about calling an external swf directly?

Comment: What do you mean call an external SWF directly? Make the panel its own SWF? I'm not sure how easy that would be to do, everything in this project is kind of a tangled mess of dependencies. In trying to make it "flexible" they ended up making it incredibly complicated to read and follow calls and variables because everything seems to be tossed around to everyone.

Comment: yes i mean embedding an external swf... you can still call data from the external swf onto the stage as well... [ http://flash-workshop.blogspot.com/2009/04/access-data-from-external-or-loaded-swf.html ] and a simple tut: [ http://www.ilike2flash.com/2009/11/load-external-swf-in-as3.html ]

Comment: It's not so much the loading part, but compiling the panel section as its own SWF separate from the entire application. I tried just copying the folder for the panel data over and I couldn't even compile it, it was missing whole core imports.